# Extracting specific words from a single cell containing text string

Tags: regex, vba, excel, excel-formula

Basically I have a very long text containing multiple spaces, special characters, etc. in one cell in an excel file and I need to extract only specific words from it, each one to a seperate cell in another column.

What I'm looing for:
symbols that are always 9 characters in lenght, and always contain at least one number (up to 9).

So for an example in A1 I have:

```
 euhe: djj33 dkdakofja.   kaowdk ---------- jffjbrjjjj j jrjj 08/01/2222 999ABC123   
 fjfjfj 321XXX888 .... ........ 123456789AA
```

And in the end I want to have:

```
999ABC123 in B1
```

and

```
321XXX888 in B2.
```

Right now I'm doing this by using Text to columns feature and then just looking for specific words manually but sometimes the volume is so big it takes too much time and would be cool to automate this.

Can anyone help with this? Thank you!

EDIT:
More examples:

```
INPUT: '10/01/2016 1,060X 8.999%!!! 1.33 0.666 928888XE0'
OUTPUT: '928888XE0'

INPUT: 'ABCDEBATX ..... ,,00,001% 20///^^ addcA7 7777a 123456789 djaoij8888888 0.000001 12@'
OUTPUT: '123456789'

INPUT: 'FAR687465 B22222222 __ djj^66 20/20/20/20 1:'
OUTPUT: 'FAR687465' in B1 'B22222222' in B2

INPUT: 'fil476 .00 20/.. BUT AAAAAAAAA k98776 000.0001'
OUTPUT: 'blank'
```

To clarify: the 9 character string can be anywhere, there is no rule what is before or after them, they can be next to each other, or just at the beginning and end of this wall of text, no rules here, the text is random, taken out of some system, can contain dates, etc anything... The symbols are always 9 characters long and they are not the only 9 character symbols in the text. I call them symbols but they should only consist of numbers and letters. Can be only numbers, but never only letters. A1 cell can contain multiple spaces/tabs between words/symbols.

Also if possible to do this not only for A1, but the whole column A until it finds the first blank cell.

Comment: Is there always a date right before your first 9 character string? Does the second string always come two strings after your first string? More examples, please.

Comment: Are the symbols **always** 9 characters and are the **only** 9-character symbol in the text? What are the rules that define how a symbol can be identified in a text string?

Comment: So special characters can be included in the 9 count? e.g. * or ( or % ? Is there a defined set of "special" characters? You say words at one point and symbols at another.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify: the 9 character string can be anywhere, there is no rule what is before or after them, they can be next to each other, or just at the beginning and end of this wall of text, no rules here, the text is random, taken out of some system, can contain dates, etc anything... The symbols are always 9 characters long and they are not the only 9 character symbols in the text. I call them symbols but they should only consist of numbers and letters. Can be only numbers, but never only letters. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
Sub Test()
Dim r           As Range
Dim i           As Long
Dim m           As Long

With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "\b[a-zA-Z\d]{9}\b"

    For Each r In Range("A1", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        If .Test(r.Value) Then
            For i = 0 To .Execute(r.Value).Count - 1
                If CBool(.Execute(r.Value)(i) Like "*[0-9]*") Then
                    m = IIf(Cells(1, 2).Value = "", 1, Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1)
                    Cells(m, 2).Value = .Execute(r.Value)(i)
                End If
            Next i
        End If
    Next r
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks but that did not work. 
Tried running it with the below example in A1:
10/01/2016     1,060X     8.999%!!!     1.33     0.666   928888XE0 
Got nothing. There are multiple spaces between the words and numbers

Comment: What is the expected output? You have to put more examples with the desired output. The code will be the same with just changing the pattern of the regex

Comment: Yes! That looks very good, thank you! Still got two minor issues: When there is more than one result for example in A1, they each go seperately to B1, then C1, then D1 instead of B1 > B2 > B3. And then I'd like to have no blanks in B column when there's no hit, just the next result from another row if possible? Thanks again!

Comment: Test2 has just one correct output in B1 and that's all, it stops there  so it's not working.

Comment: I tested on your examples and I could extract all the correct results .. Working for me. Please put some snapshots of the input and output after executing the code

Comment: You have to put all your input in A1 if you will deal with Test2

Comment: You are correct, thank you. Is there a possibility of combining Test1 and Test2? Input in multiple A cells, output only in B cells, one under the other?

Comment: I have updated the code to suit your needs .. I didn't get a point for all these changes :)

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you! I do not have enough reputation to have my votes publicly displayed but it should be recorded, thank you once again! :)

Answer (score 0):

This bit of code is almost it... just need to check the strings... but excel crashes on the Str line of code

```
Sub Test()
    Dim Outputs, i As Integer, LastRow As Long, Prueba, Prueba2
    Outputs = Split(Range("A1"), " ")
    For i = 0 To UBound(Outputs)
        If Len(Outputs(i)) = 9 Then
            Prueba = 0
            Prueba2 = 0
            On Error Resume Next
            Prueba = Val(Outputs(i))
            Prueba2 = Str(Outputs(i))
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Prueba <> 0 And Prueba2 <> 0 Then
                LastRow = Range("B10000").End(xlUp).Row + 1
                Cells(LastRow, 2) = Outputs(i)
            End If
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

If someone could help to set the string check.. that would do the thing I guess.